# regex JavaScript with repeating string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to parse with regex files with the following format in order to retrieve content1a, content1b,content2a,content2b, etc ...

```
===
content1a
===
content1b
===
content2a
===
content2b
```

Important : the end of file does not contain ===

This regex does almost the job :

```
/[===[\s\S]*?===[.]*/g
```

but does not retrieve the last content (content2b)

Thank you for helping

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^===\n(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/2CCNGP/1

Comment: perfect in php, almost in js. Thanks

Comment: ... for the provided use case something like ... [`str.match(/^(?!\=).*$/gm)`](https://regex101.com/r/D38ItR/1) ... already should be sufficient enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern that you tried uses a character class, which can also be written as `[\s\S]*?===` or `([^]*?)===`

It expects `===` to be there at the end, that is why is does not match the last content.

But if you have for example 5 times an equals sign `=====` you will also match the last 2 equals signs, so you could add a newline to prevent that.

---

Instead of using `[\s\S]*?` You could use a capturing group to capture all lines that do not start with `===`

```
^===\n((?:(?!===\n).*\n?)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mRAzCm/1)

```js
const regex = /^===\n((?:(?!===\n).*\n?)*)/gm;
const str = `===
content1a
===
content1b
===
content2a
content2a
content2a
===
content2b`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: Same : perfect in php, almost in js. Thanks

Comment: @tit I have added a js example

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regex you can just split the string

```js
const str = `===
content1a
===
content1b
===
content2a
===
content2b`;

const contents = str.split('===\n').filter(f => f !== "");

console.log(contents);
```

Comment: this is not a regex, but nice!

Comment: No and by not being a regex it's easier to read and probably marginally more efficient. ["Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) (though I don't really subscribe to this opinion myself)

Comment: I would change the split value to `(/\n*===\n/)`; thus the filtered values from the split-list will not anymore be terminated by `\n`.